# Saving a specific row using PHP and a search option

Tags: php, html, oracle

I have the following program, it searchs for the text placed in a previous php file, and it displays the results, by adding a radiobox to check the item that will be purchased. I am not able to make the page save the item that was checked from the items found into a new table, I don't know how to do that, because the items found are placed as fetched items, therefore I don't know how to select one to save the entire row selected. Please help!.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Search option</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
echo "<form action='slips.php' method='post'>";
if(isset($_POST['name_prod2'])){ 
$word=$_POST['name_prod2']; 

$conn = oci_pconnect('dbname', 'password', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['Error'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM product WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%" . $word . "%'");
oci_execute($stid);

echo "<table width='950' table border='1' align='center'>\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<th width='50'> <div align='center'>buy</div></th>";
    echo "<th width='110'> <div align='center'>Product ID</div></th>";
    echo "<th width='190'> <div align='center'>Product name</div></th>";
    echo "<th width='250'> <div align='center'>Description</div></th>";
    echo "<th width='100'> <div align='center'>in Store</div></th>";
    echo "<th width='100'> <div align='center'>price</div></th>";
    echo "<th width='190'> <div align='center'>Quantity to purchase</div></th>";
    echo "</tr>\n";

while ($product = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {

    echo "<tr>\n";  
    //echo "<td><div style='text-align:center'><label><input type='radio' name='radio1' value='valor'></label></td></div>";
    echo sprintf('<td><div style="text-align:center"><label><input type="radio" name="product" value="%s"></label></td></div>', $product['product_id']);

    foreach ($product as $aspect) {
    echo '<td><div style="text-align:center">'.($aspect !== null ? htmlentities($aspect, ENT_QUOTES) : '')."</td></div>\n";
    }
    echo '<td width="50"><div align="center"><input name="quantity" type="text" size="27" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter quantity"></div></td>';

}
echo "</table>\n";
}
echo "<div style='text-align:center'><input type='submit' value='Comprar'></div>";
echo"</form>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

These are two of the Javascripts that I have tried so far to complete this, but they fail to tell me when one has been selected, I don't know if I can try adding this code to a button, and when I click it, it will tell me which row from the radio box was checked, and then save it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var user_cat = $("input[radio1='user_cat']:checked").val();
if (!$("input[radio1='radio1']").is(':checked')) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
}
else {
   alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btnStatus').click(function(){
      var isChecked = $('#rdSelect').prop('checked');
      alert(isChecked);
   });
});

</script>
```

When is use this line `echo "<td><div style='text-align:center'><label><input type='radio' name='radio1' value='valor'></label></td></div>";` it works and displays this [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nayxc.jpg)

But when I use this line `echo sprintf('<td><div style="text-align:center"><label><input type="radio" name="product" value="%d"></label></td></div>', $product['product_id']);`it doesn't work and displays this [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHuuw.jpg)

Comment: Well, since you are not using a form you do not post anything to the server. So instead you have to act on the client side. You implement an event handler in javascript which reacts on a radio box getting checked In that handler you make an ajax call to the server where the information can be processed. There are many, many examples for this to be found on google or wherever.

Comment: I have tried implementing three different event handlers in javascript, one of them using jQuery, but they didn't work at all. They work when the page is loaded, but once you click on a radiobox, it does not display that it was checked.

Comment: There is nothing we can say to this: "did not work" has never helped anyone anywhere. You have to show what you tried, otherwise everything is guessing.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in helping me, I have updated my question, with the javascripts that I have tried so far, please check it. I hope I can complete this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, picking up the information from the comments to the question and doing a little guess work I will try to point you into the right direction. It is not possible to give a read-to-use answer, since still there are things not clear, but let's have a try to get started...

I see you have an html form which includes a table. That table has a header row and dynamic generated rows holding some product information each. You want to have a radio button in front of each row to allow to select a row. And you want a text input field at the end of each row which allows to enter a quantity. Then you want to post that information to the server to be able to process it.

I will stick with the "conservative" html approach and not introduce scripting here. Reason is that for the purpose described before that is not required. So let's keep things simple. Obviously nothing speaks against making things more complicated later on :-)

Your radio buttons have to be changed, they currently make no sense. You have to give the an individual value, so that you can identify which row has been selected later on. Currently you give them all the same static value 'value'. So change the loop that iterates over the products to something like:

```
while ($product = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";  
    echo sprintf('<td><div style="text-align:center"><label><input type="radio" name="product" value="%s"></label></td></div>'."\n", $product['product_id']);

    foreach ($row as $aspect) {
        echo '<td><div style="text-align:center">' 
            .($aspect !== null ? htmlentities($aspect, ENT_QUOTES) : '')
            ."</td></div>\n";
    }
    echo '<td width="50"><div align="center"><input name="quantity" type="text" size="27" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter quantity"></div></td>'."\n";
}
```

Note: I took the liberty to change the chosen names to be more logical to `product`, `aspect` and `quantity`...

That is all... Now when you press the submit button the form should get posted to the target you specified: `slips.php` which is probably a script of yours... Inside that script you now can access the data like that:

```
$product  = $_POST['product'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
```

There are more issue worth discussing and modifying, but as said: let's keep things simple and take one step after the other!

---

ChangeLog:

- changed the literal key of the array element used as a value inside the radio button definition from `id` to `procduct_id` according to one of the comments below

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73584/discussion-on-answer-by-arkascha-saving-a-specific-row-using-php-and-a-search-op).

Answer (score 0):

Your radiobox need to stay inside the form.

Comment: I have done that, but I am still not able to save into a new table the row that is selected, from the results of the search.